# Laravel Cashier - Lifetime Subscription

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

i am trying to do monthly, yearly and lifetime subscription in which monthly and yearly subscription is working fine. how can i do lifetime/forever subscription? whenever i pass the plan name and plan id to `$user->newSubscription()` i get an error:

```
You passed a non-recurring price but this field only accepts recurring prices.
```

below is my code for subscription:

```
$paymentMethod = $user->defaultPaymentMethod();

        if ($period == 'yearly') {
            $selectedPlan = $plan->plan_year;
        } elseif($period=='monthly') {
            $selectedPlan = $plan->plan_month;
        }
        else{
            $selectedPlan = $plan->plan_lifetime;
        }   

        $subscription = $user->newSubscription($plan->name, $selectedPlan);
```

Comment: Maybe don't make a subscription, since it's lifetime you can just make one payment.

Comment: but then how i will check if user subscribed or did payment already.

Comment: According to your database. In any case, you shouldn't rely on one processing solution (Stripe) and their code. What happens if you have to switch them, or add another payment method?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using [prices](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/prices-guide) instead of plans, your should create an invoice instead of a subscription:

```php
if ($period == 'yearly') {
    $subscription = $user->newSubscription($plan->name, $plan->plan_year);
} elseif($period=='monthly') {
    $subscription = $user->newSubscription($plan->name, $plan->plan_month);
} else {
    // Create an invoice item with the lifetime price
    StripeInvoiceItem::create([
        'customer' => $user->stripeId(),
        'price' => $plan->plan_lifetime,
    ], $user->stripeOptions());

    // create the invoice with the lifetime item and finalize it automatically after 1 hour
    $user->invoice(['auto_advance' => true]);
}
```

Next, add `invoice.paid` to your webhooks and your need to listen for this notification by extending the WebhookController. Here you will find the matching invoice and check if the invoice item has the same id as `$plan->lifetime_plan`. If so, you can update a column on your customer model to set that the have a lifetime subscription:

```php
public function handleInvoicePaid(array $payload)
{
    if ($user = $this->getUserByStripeId($payload['data']['object']['customer'])) {
        $data = $payload['data']['object'];

        $invoice = $user->findInvoice($data['id']);

        if (isset($invoice)) {
            $plan = ...

            if ($invoice->invoiceItems()->contains(function (InvoiceLineItem $item) use ($plan) {
                return $item->price->id === $plan->lifetime_plan;
            })) {
                $user->update(['has_lifetime_subscription' => true]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->successMethod();
}
```

In your applications, you can check if the user has a lifetime subscription or a normal subscription:

```php
if ($user->has_lifetime_subscription || $user->subscribed()) {
    // ...
}
```